# Camera preview and picture sizes matching aspect ratio option guaranteed?

Tags: android

I'm using the camera's `getSupportedPictureSizes()` and `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` methods. Is there any guarantee that there will be at least one option in both that will have the same aspect ratio? Example device sizes:

```
// on this device, all options have a 0.75 aspect ratio.
List<Camera.Size> pictureSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
  960 x 720, 0.75
  640 x 480, 0.75   
  1600 x 1200, 0.75  
  2048 x 1536, 0.75
  2560 x 1920, 0.75


// We have some matching preview sizes.
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(); 
  1280 x 720, 0.5625
  1024 x 576, 0.5625
  768 x 512, 0.66
  1024 x 768, 0.75  // *match
  640 x 480, 0.75   // *match
  320 x 240, 0.75   // *match
  352 x 288, 0.81
```

On my 8 test devices, I always find an aspect ratio match. Wondering if there is any statement by google, or some research done that says this is to be expected, or this is just a nice coincidence.

Thanks